# How do I extract different fields of a filename in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I have some log files to fuse. The filenames are of format `environment.type-YYYY-MM-DD.log` where:

- `environment` represents the server's environment: "private", "public", "para", etc.)
- `type` is "primary", "secondary", "error", etc.
- `YYYY-MM-DD` represents the date of file creation.

All files types are found in all servers: "primary", "secondary" and "error" files are found in the private, public and para servers; e.g `private.error-2021-09-10.log`, `public.error-2021-09-11.log`, `public.primary-2021-09-08.log`, `public.error-2021-15.log`.

Since files of the same type can be found in the different servers, I have to fuse the primary files of the public, private and para servers separately and do same for the error and secondary files. The files must equally be fused on a date range (fusion of files per 7 days in a month).

My approach is then to use conditions that will:

1. Compare the servers' names (public, private and para) with the ones in the files' names in order to group the files according to their corresponding server.
2. Compare the file types (error, primary and secondary) with the ones in the files' names in order to fuse only files of corresponding types in each of their servers.
3. Compare the date range (maximum of 7 days in a month to have a fused file).

For this, I will need commands that would enable me to extract the server name, file type and date to compare with the values I will include in my conditions and fuse the files separately as stated in my approach above.

I tried using: `*.log | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1}'` to extract the environment (field 1) part and I tried `*.log | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $2}'` to extract the file type (field 2) but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the "standard value" you're comparing against?

Comment: for example if I want to fuse files of the public server together, my standard value will be 'public' for that particular condition. So I have to extract the server name from the file's name and compare its value with 'public'(for this case) so that if it maches, the file will be grouped with public files of the same type but if it doesn't match with public, the file will not be grouped with public files.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example set of filenames:

```
private.error-2021-09-10.log
public.error-2021-09-11.log
public.primary-2021-09-08.log
public.error-2021-15.log
```

I am assuming that the missing "-MM-" portion of the last filename is a typo...

Here is an example using awk that may work for you:

Get "environment":

`ls *.log | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}'`

Result:

```
private
public
public
public
```

Get "type":

`ls *.log | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}'`

Result:

```
error
error
error
primary
```

Get date stamp:

`ls *.log | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $3 "-" $4 "-" $5}'`

Result:

```
2021-09-10
2021-09-11
2021-15-log
2021-09-08
```

**Edit:**
From the comment below, I wanted to add options that don't parse the output of `ls` as that's prone to other problems.

You might try this:

```bsh
for file in *.log; do
  echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}'
  echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $2}'
  echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $3 "-" $4 "-" $5}'
done
```

or something with find (`find -type f -name "*.log" -exec awk -f'[.-]' '{print $1}' {} +;`) but there are gotchas to be aware of there, too.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your log files are all matched by the filename globbing pattern `*.*-*.log`, you may loop over their names and extract the different parts into separate variables.

```bsh
for name in *.*-*.log; do
        tmpname=$name

        environment=${tmpname%%.*}; tmpname=${tmpname#*.}
        type=${tmpname%%-*};        tmpname=${tmpname#*-}
        date=${tmpname%.log}

        printf '"%s" --> %s + %s + %s\n' \
                "$name" "$type" "$environment" "$date"
done
```

This code extracts the different parts of the names into the three variables `environment`, `type`, and `date`.  We're using successive steps to extract and delete each piece from a copy of the name in `tmpname`. We are using standard parameter substitutions, which is faster than using `awk` several times.

Example of running this:

```
$ ls
list                                public.error-2021-15.log
private.error-2021-09-10.log        public.primary-2021-09-08.log
public.error-2021-09-11.log         script
```

```
$ ./script
"private.error-2021-09-10.log" --> error + private + 2021-09-10
"public.error-2021-09-11.log" --> error + public + 2021-09-11
"public.error-2021-15.log" --> error + public + 2021-15
"public.primary-2021-09-08.log" --> primary + public + 2021-09-08
```