# How can I keep an extracted value in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, awk, variable

I have to extract certain values from some filenames in a directory and I wish to have a command to keep the extracted value in a variable. Say my files have the format `place.type-date.log` and I wish to extract and keep place in a variable called `first`, how can I do it?

I tried to use

```bsh
first=$($file | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}')
```

but it didn't work.

Normally if I do

```bsh
echo " place.type-date.log" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}'
```

and the result will be `place`. So I just replaced `place.type-date.log` by `$file` in my command because I have to do it for multiple files in a particular directory where I used a for loop.

I want to store the extracted value `place` in the variable `first` that is why I equated the extraction command to the variable `first`. So when I tried to `echo first`, and I executed my script, it didn't show anything meaning the extracted value had not been stored in the variable.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean, exactly? What did you expect to happen, what happened instead? In general, we can't know your situation exactly, and if you gave details, it'd be easier for the readers to help you. And in this case, the error message you get should help reveal the matter.

Comment: What is `$file` ?? What happens when yo run that command without saving to variable? I can't see how `$file | some_command` will possibly work if `$file` is not a command/script itself, so the issue is not how to save in variable, but the initial command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a filename like `place.type-date.log` in the variable `file`, and you want to store the part of the filename before the first dot in another variable called `first`. In that case, you may do that using a standard parameter substitution.

```bsh
first=${file%%.*}
```

The above removes the longest suffix matching the shell pattern `.*` from the value of `$file` and stores the result in `first`.

Using `%` in place of `%%` would remove the shortest matching suffix instead, leaving `place.type-date`.  Using `#` or `##` in place of `%` and `%%`  would remove prefix strings rather than suffix strings.

For another example of using these substitutions, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670967/493832) to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669321/493832).

---

Your code does not work because `$file` is the string `place.type-date.log`, not a command.  You may have attempted to do something like

```bsh
first=$( echo "$file" | awk -F '[.-]' '{ print $1 }' )
```

But this is more complicated than it needs to be. It also has some issues regarding escape sequences in filenames (which `echo` may expand) and filenames containing newlines (`awk` is a line-oriented text processing tool).

Comment: I just needed to add echo before "$file" as you said. Thanks so much. it works perfectly now.

Comment: @NgouabaRosalie I would suggest you use the variable substitution method that I showed first in my answer instead of using `awk` for this.  It is slow to run `awk` like this in a loop, and you will find that your code runs many times faster when using the variable substitution.

Comment: Note that `echo` can mangle data. Better to use `printf`. And `awk` processes one line at a time, so would be a problem with file names that contain newline characters.